# Zend Framework: Request seems to be outdated by 1 request

Tags: zend-framework

I seem to experiencing a weird error where my request params seem to be outdated by 1 request

my login code @ [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GUT1r59V)

I have tried to illustrate my point in a video @ [screenr](http://screenr.com/YLX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly like it should, this is the intended behavior of FlashMessenger helper.

What FlashMessenger does is store the messages you add in session. It *only* loads them from the session upon constructing a new FlashMessenger object; that is when the *next* request occurs. This is the whole point of FlashMessenger; to pass messages from one request to the another; not to pass messages within the same request (for that, you just use regular variables, or storage such as `Zend_Registry`).

What you usually do with FlashMessenger is that you first add a message, and you then redirect to the same (or another) page, using eg. the _redirect method, or the Redirector action helper. It's convenient to subclass the Zend_Controller class, and add your own helper method that lets you do both of these in single method, such as a method called _flash. For instance I usually do something like this:

```
<?php

class App_Controller extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $_messages = array();

    protected function _flash($message, $to = false)
    {
        $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
        if ($message)
            $flashMessenger->addMessage($message);
        if (!$to)
            $to = $this->_request->getRequestUri();
        $this->_redirect($to);
    }

    public function postDispatch()
    {
        // Set flash messages
        $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
        $this->view->messages = array_merge($this->_messages, $flashMessenger->getMessages());
    }
}
```

I then simply do `$this->_flash("My message");` which will do two things: 1) Add the message to the flash message stack and 2) Refresh the page.

You can also see that I have a `protected $_messages`, the reason for this is that if I want to display a message without having to refresh the page, I can simply append a message to that array.